# sqoop server start failed

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, sqoop2

I am trying to connect to a `sqoop` server on localhost:

```
sqoop:000> set server --host manager --port 12000 --webapp sqoop
Server is set successfully
sqoop:000> show version -all
client version:
  Sqoop 1.99.6 source revision 07244c3915975f26f03d9e1edf09ab7d06619bb8 
  Compiled by root on Wed Apr 29 10:40:43 CST 2015
0    [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader  - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception has occurred during processing command 
Exception: org.apache.sqoop.common.SqoopException Message: CLIENT_0000:An unknown error has occurred
sqoop:000> 


Port 12000 is closed

    $ netstat -na|grep 12000
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Ah,I don't find any erros in the log.

Comment: Because of the sqoop server started failed.

Answer (score 2):

Hadoop libraries need to be set in a file named `catalina.properties` inside directory `server/conf`. In this file, you need to set the hadoop libraries path in `common-loader` property. Default will be `/usr/lib/hadoop` and `/usr/lib/hadoop/lib`. If you have your hadoop libraries at any different locations then point that directory in this property.

`sqoop2-tool verify` can be used to verify all the sqoop server configurations. If it is successful, you can start your server using `sqoop2-server start`.

**Ref:**
https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.99.6/Installation.html

Comment: Something to keep in mind, I also had to change `org.apache.sqoop.submission.engine.mapreduce.configuration.directory` to my hadoop configuration directory. For the `2.7 homebrew installation`, that path is `/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.2/libexec/etc/hadoop` Also, one thing that is confusing from the 5 minute quick start documentation is that it doesn't tell you to start your server with the `sqoop2-server start` before checking the version.